# Common test for CYPRESS with constants

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress

I installed CYPRES but I have  thirty sites to test.
Is it possible to write tests in order to have the test only once in a common folder, and a list of constants for each site:

In a common folder:

```
describe('Test URL', () => {
  it('Home ', () => {
    cy.visit(LIST OF URL)               
  })
})
```

In a folder foreach website:

```
LIST OF URL = '/home,/contact,/faq';
```

For the form for example:

```
describe('Form', () => {
  it('form, () => {
        cy.visit('/contact')
        })
  it('field name', () => {
    cy.get(PATH FIELD_NAME) 
      .type('test') 
    })    
  it('mail field', () => {
    cy.get(PATH FIELD_MAIL)
      .type('test@test.com') 
    })
```

In a folder foreach website:

```
PATH FIELD_NAME = 'input#name';
PATH FIELD_MAIL = 'input#mail';
```

It would be easier to maintain.

I don't see how to do this. Is was possible?

Answer (score 0):

If by sites you mean pages of a single site, then you can take a data driven approach

```js
const urls = ['/home', '/contact', '/faq']

describe('Test URL', () => {

  urls.forEach(url => 

    it(`Testing ${url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)               
    })
  })
})
```

The form does not seem to be repetitious, for example is name & email on the `/home` or `/faq` pages?

If you use the same page (e.g /contact) on multiple websites, and it's the same each time, you may be able to use [component testing](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/introducing-the-cypress-component-test-runner/) and test it just once.